# how to create elasticsearch cluster with docker compose in different servers?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, cluster-computing

I have 2 servers, and create elasticsearch nodes in the 2 servers. the content of docker-compose.yml files are like these:

```
es0:
    image: elasticsearch:7.6.0
    container_name: es0
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    volumes:
      - "/mnt/docker/es0/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"
      - "/mnt/docker/es0/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
      - "/mnt/docker/es0/plugins:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins"
      - "/mnt/docker/es0/config/cert:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/cert"
```

---

```
  es1:
    image: elasticsearch:7.6.0
    container_name: es1
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    volumes:
      - "/mnt/docker/es1/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"
      - "/mnt/docker/es1/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
      - "/mnt/docker/es1/plugins:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins"
      - "/mnt/docker/es1/config/cert:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/cert"
```

and I configured the elasticsearch.yml like these:

```
cluster.name: hs-cluster
node.name: es-00
node.master: true
node.data: true
http.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
transport.host: 0.0.0.0
transport.tcp.port: 9300
#network.host: 0.0.0.0 
network.bind_host: ["192.168.0.2", "101.xx.xx.136"]
network.publish_host: 192.168.0.2

gateway.recover_after_nodes: 1

http.cors.enabled: true 
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"

cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["es-00", "es-01"] 
discovery.seed_hosts: [ "192.168.0.2:9300", "192.168.0.3:9300" ]

bootstrap.memory_lock: true
bootstrap.system_call_filter: false
```

---

```
cluster.name: hs-cluster
node.name: es-01
node.master: true
node.data: true
http.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
transport.host: 0.0.0.0
transport.tcp.port: 9300
#network.host: 0.0.0.0 
network.bind_host: ["192.168.0.3", "101.xx.xx.137"]
network.publish_host: 192.168.0.3

gateway.recover_after_nodes: 1

http.cors.enabled: true 
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"

cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["es-00", "es-01"] 
discovery.seed_hosts: [ "192.168.0.2:9300", "192.168.0.3:9300" ]

bootstrap.memory_lock: true
bootstrap.system_call_filter: false
```

when I run the instances, they all started successfully. But when I call _cluster/state?pretty, they all gave the error message:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
        "reason" : null
      }
    ],
    "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
    "reason" : null
  },
  "status" : 503
}
```

that means they can't find each other. 
I also tried to set *`network.host: 0.0.0.0`*
but the result was the same. 
Who know the reason of this master not discovered exception? How to resolve it?

btw, I can ran the cluster in the same server with docker compose. But in different servers, it is failed. I also ran telnet xxx 9300 in each server, they all connected.

Comment: In your docker compose files, you have no network section?

Comment: Is that use default bridge network if I don't set any networks? Actually I'm not familiar with it. I tried setting networks as bridge:
    networks:
      - elastic

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge

But the result is the same.

Comment: I set the network-mode as host, then it works. Thank you! I'll try bridge mode next.

Comment: Yes, indeed, if you use the host network the container will share the host’s networking namespace and they can see each other.

Comment: @LiuTao - Can you share the right configuration please ?

Answer (score 0):

> What is your default docker-engine network configuration?

Sometimes multiple servers have the same network, so dockers don't route from one server to another.

To resolve this you have to modify the `daemon.json` file to the following:

```json
node1
{
    "bip": "10.40.18.1/28"
}
node2
{
    "bip": "10.40.18.65/28"
}
```